# Really Cheap Public Access Point

Tags: access-point

I have a number of DSL customers that wish to offer free wireless at their business.  They wish to have a terms and conditions page and we wish to have a little free advertising on that page.  Seems ridiculously simple.

I know I could build the gateways for around $200 with a cheap little Linux (acer revo? fit-pc?) box and a bridged access point gizmo (DAP-15xx?).

But I'm looking for sub hundred dollar solutions that could do this.  I was trying to figure out if DD-WRT could do it, but I couldn't get any clear feeling about it from their wiki.  If DD-WRT can do it, then there are some really great $60 products that come with DD-WRT running as the native firmware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe DD-WRT can accomplish this by the chilispot service that it's capable of running.  I haven't done this but it always looked interesting to turn on.

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot#Executive_Summary

```
Executive Summary

ChilliSpot (chilli, chillispot) is a way to...

    * Easily make the wireless or lan-connected computers display a 'landing page' on user's browsers.

    * Redirection occurs on the first web page, and until the user clicks through (I Agree/Login). 

    ...
```

I've always used buffalo AP's, they are easy to flash, cheap, and rock solid.  Just find the latest recommended model on their page and you should be good to go.

Comment: Awesome. I definitely need to locate a dd-wrt and try that.